# Using hector_slam for localization

Tags: ros, robotics

I'm doing some reaserch for navigation algorithms in ROS and so far I have been using amcl for localization. Now I want to try different localization algotithms like hector_slam, so I'm a bit confused. When I run hector_slam does it publish map to odom transformation like amcl or does it publish its own odom and I need amcl for transformation from map to odom? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hector_mapping DOES publish odometry.** It can be used by setting "pub_odometry" parameter to "true". It also publishes "map" frame to "odom" frame transform.

You can use hector_mapping instead of amcl, but you can do so only while also mapping the environment, and not on a pre-made map, as you would do with amcl.

If you wish to exploit the fact that hector_mapping gives good odometry, you have the option of publishing odometry via the node and then use amcl with it, as explained in [this q&a](https://answers.ros.org/question/104971/using-hector-slam-with-amcl-for-localization-in-a-pre-made-map/).

It is a straightforward process. Remap the map frame and topic name in hector launch file to something else. Set pub_odometry to true. Set pub_map_odom_transform to false (because this will be published by amcl). If your robot base also publishes odom, remap it to something else so it doesn't interfere with hector's. Give the odom topic to amcl. I've tested it on my robot and it works great, a lot better than odom from encoders which get inaccurate when surface friction changes.

Answer (score 0):

hector_slam is only launch file, actual node is **hector_mapping**, on Wiki page following topics are mentioned as published:

*map_metadata (nav_msgs/MapMetaData)*

*map (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid)*

*slam_out_pose (geometry_msgs/PoseStamped)*

*poseupdate (geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped)*

**amcl** topics are:

*amcl_pose (geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped)*

*particlecloud (geometry_msgs/PoseArray)*

*tf (tf/tfMessage)*

Not sure if I understood your question, but you need additional ***tf*** topic for ***hector*** if you want to publish map to different frame.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes I was thinking about hector_mapping node, and I already have a pre-built map of the environment so I need hector_mapping to publish map to odom tf or I can use odometry published by hector_mapping and pass that odometry to amcl to use for map to odom tf.

Comment: As far as I know odometry is the use of data from motion sensors to estimate change in position over time, what exactly do you mean by I need hector_mapping to publish map to odom tf? Also hector_mapping doesn't publish odometry.